# How to find the vector of this common light bulb logo?

Tags: vector, images

Apologies if this is not the right place for posting questions like these - first time posting here so please feel free to remove/flag this question if it's not suitable.

I'm looking for a light bulb vector logo like the one in the link below. I have a feeling it's from Pixabay. However I can't seem to find it. I tried using a google image search with filetype:svg but didn't get any useful results.

http://swagawardsjax.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/SWAG-Awards-Einstein-Icon-2.png

Comment: You could just draw it using vector software. It should only take a couple of minutes - much less time than trying "to find" it. Obviously it would need to be your own creation rather than a direct copy (for copyright reasons).

Comment: Thank you @BillyKerr. This was really useful!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about graphic design, but about finding a specific resource online.

Answer (score 3):

You could go to the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=bulb) and search for "bulb" and there will be over 12,000 vector format light bulbs to choose from, many of which quite similar to your example. Just be careful about their usage terms, most, if not all, require you to either purchase the artwork or mention the author's name when using the artwork.

Comment: Didn't know about this. Thank you @Lucian for this link!

Answer (score 1):

There are many websites to download this type of vector icons. I regularly use the below website for these types of vectors icons:

- [Icons8](https://icons8.com)
- [Flaticon](https://flaticon.com)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [Feather Icons](https://feathericons.com/), this one works with NPM and looks really nice!